# Error when creating Object of a Object in angular 10

Tags: angular, angular-directive

```
export class School {
    constructor(
        
        public name: string,
        public address: Address,
        public district: string,
        public contactNumber: string,
        public gradeRange: string,
        public currentYear: number,
        public trialAcct: boolean,
        public customerInfo: CustomerInfo,
        public composing: boolean,
        public createdAt: number,
        
    ){}
    export class Address{
            streetAddress1: string;
            streetAddress2:string;
            city: string;
            state: string;
            postalCode: string;

    }

    export class CustomerInfo{
        public customerID: string;
        public paymentID: string;
        public subscriptionID: string;
        public maskedPayment: string;
        public firstName: string;
        public lastName: string;
    }
```

that's the model i defined for the data, when creating object of this class with the data i get from api then it gives me address was not provided. But in the data address is provided.
this is how i create object of this,

```
getSchool(): School {
    return new School(this.schooldata);
  }
```

and this.schooldata contains data in it.

I have No idea where should i get the error

Answer (score 0):

your constructors accepts a lot of parameters, not an object

```
constructor(
        
        public name: string,
        public address: Address,
        public district: string,
        public contactNumber: string,
        public gradeRange: string,
        public currentYear: number,
        public trialAcct: boolean,
        public customerInfo: CustomerInfo,
        public composing: boolean,
        public createdAt: number,
        
    ){}
```

valid way of calling your constructor should be

```
new School(name, address, district, contactNumber, etc....);
```

Comment: but how? should i have to map every single key of these

Answer (score 0):

It is best to use interface and pass it on.

```
export interface objProp{
   name: string,
   address: Address,
   district: string,
   contactNumber: string,
   gradeRange: string,
   currentYear: number,
   trialAcct: boolean,
   customerInfo: CustomerInfo,
   composing: boolean,
   createdAt: number,
}
```

Comment: well i can use the interface but how is it different from that i am using? and how can i pass it.